# AWS Aurora timeouts due to 100% cpu utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am trying to do load testing on AWS aurora, i am hitting 20k request in 2mins.
When database endpoints are pointing to mysql server(non-aws) everything is running smooth, but when I change database endpoint to point to AWS aurora , connections are timing out after about 20-30secs and in dashes I can see 100% cpu utilization during the run.

AWS support people are saying to optimize your query and use select on specific fields rather than select *.
But my question is, If in mysql server everything is running good. Then Why aurora cant perform similar way?

Comment: 20k requests in 120 seconds is quite high. What Instance Class are you using for the Aurora database? Are you running the queries from within AWS (eg from an Amazon EC2 instance), or is it from the Internet? If you are doing `SELECT *` across a lot of data, then you might be hitting bandwidth limits between you and the database. AWS Support are very knowledgeable about their systems, so I'd tend to trust what they are saying.

Comment: Hi John, we are using db.r3.xlarge this, yes we are running queries with AWS from EC2.
and ideally we have to reach 40k request in 120 sec which is also running good with mysql server(non aws).

Answer (score 1):

As Aurora has one master and multiple read replicas for read operations. Eariler all read/write was being handled by master instance only and read replica nodes were not at all used. So, when we changed the behaviour such that read requests will go to read replicas and write requests to master, issue got resolved.